# Why Can't I Bevel This Object?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, svg

I've got this object which started as an SVG file.  I've used solidify and bevel on the curve but it will not bevel no matter what I do.

So I converted it into a mesh.  I've converted tris to quads.  I still can't get the edge to bevel.

What can I do?

BLEND FILE:
[howdoibevelthis.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1vfrjsj2pq4lt8/howdoibevelthis.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the Bevel modifier will work fine with a curve, what you can do is go into the Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry and give your curve an Extrude value and a Bevel > Round or Profile: https://zupimages.net/up/21/04/4btx.jpg

Comment: Thank you for that. This is exactly what I'm looking for.  In regards to that link being basically the same... should I delete this question? New here, sorry.

Comment: No you can keep it open